# How to print uiwebview which has header and uitableview with multiple data

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiwebview, ios12, uiprintinteractioncntrler

I am creating webview to print the data. As per my requirement half of the page contains header labels and remaining starts with uitableview which has table contents.

If tableview contents are more then i need to continue those contents to next page.

```
func createPDF(_ currentWebView: UIWebView)
{        
    let date = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let dateComponents: DateComponents = (calendar as NSCalendar).components([.month, .day, .year], from: date)
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium
    let dateFormatter1 = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy"
    let strOrderDate = NSString(format: "Date: " + dateFormatter1.string(from: date) as NSString)
    let ID = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "ID") as! String

    lblValue.text = ""
    lblValue.text = "Value: " + ID
    lblTotalItems.text = "Total items: " + (totalNumberofItems as String)

    lblDate.text = strOrderDate as String
    tblContainer.tableFooterView = UIView()
    tblContainer.reloadData()

    for eachView: UIView in self.view.subviews
    {
        if(eachView.isKind(of: UILabel.self) || eachView.isKind(of: UIView.self) )
        {
            if(eachView != self.view && eachView != currentWebView)
            {
                currentWebView.addSubview(eachView)
            }
        }
    }

   let heightStr: NSString = currentWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.body.scrollHeight")! as NSString
   let height : Int = heightStr.integerValue
   let screenHeight: CGFloat = currentWebView.bounds.size.height;
   let pages = Int(ceil(screenHeight/CGFloat(height)))

    let frame: CGRect = currentWebView.frame
    var currentContext: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    for i: Int in 0..<pages
    {
        if (Int(CGFloat(i+1) * screenHeight) > height)
        {
            var f: CGRect = currentWebView.frame
            f.size.height = f.size.height - CGFloat((CGFloat(i + 1) * screenHeight) - CGFloat(height));
            currentWebView.frame = f
        }
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        currentWebView.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: screenHeight * CGFloat(i)) , animated: false)
        currentWebView.layer.render(in: currentContext)
    }
    currentWebView.frame = frame
}
```

My problem is : If tableview contents are more and scrollable, i want to display those content also in second page but that is not happening.

Tableview is getting cut on the same page.

Any body has any idea about that.. Please help!

Thanks

Comment: UIWebView is deprecated in iOS 12.

Comment: Yes..But it is working fine if content fits in the same screen...only problem is with more content comes

Comment: You probably won't be able to publish new apps using `UIWebView`. It really is deprecated. Use `WKWebView` instead.

Comment: Tried with WKWebView also..but no luck.. still tableview whole content is not displaying in next page.

Comment: just curious why are you adding UIViews in WebView? If you want to use webview why don't you create html table and then display it in webview. that would be much easier..

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are messing with finding the number of pages to generate. Please try the following code to calculate the page.

```
   let heightStr: NSString = currentWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from:       "document.body.scrollHeight")! as NSString
   let height : Int = heightStr.integerValue
   let screenHeight: CGFloat = currentWebView.bounds.size.height
// ******** Change is here. *******
   let pages = Int(ceil(CGFloat(height)/screenHeight))
```

Hope this will work. Happy Coding :)